# Python RegEx capturing first word after pattern

Tags: python, regex

Possible strings are:

1. `public class MyClass extends ParentClass {`

or

1. `public class MyClass throws SomeException {`

or just

1. `public class MyClass {`

I am using the following pattern to always capture `MyClass`:

```
ptrn = "((public|private|protected)\s+(.*)\s*[class|interface]\s+(\w+))"
```

But when I do

```
regex = re.search(ptrn, text)

className = regex.group(4)
```

for 1 and 2 I get `ParentClass` and `SomeException` respectively and only for 3 I get `MyClass`.

What is wrong with my regex pattern and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
strings = ("public class MyClass extends ParentClass {","public class MyClass throws SomeException {","public class MyClass {")
pattern = "((public|private|protected)\s+(class|interface)\s+(\w+))"

for string in strings:
    print re.search(pattern,string).group(4)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Python, but I do know regex fairly well. What you are looking for is something more like:
`(public|private|protected)\s+(class|interface)\s+(\w+)`

I don't know which group that would be in Python, but it most other languages, it'd be group 3 (0 would be the whole string, 1 would be public, private or protected, 2 would be class or interface, 3 would be your class name.)

Answer (score 2):

`[class|interface]` is a character class; essentially it will match any one of these characters.  Instead, you probably want to use `(class|interface)`

http://rubular.com/r/Jc6o3SAhi3